# Running external program via Qt crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I have trouble with my program: my goal is to run console program from Qt GUI when I click on button. Slot looks like this:

```
void on_Button_clicked(){
     QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("filepath",QUrl::TolerantMode));
}
```

Simple console programs like "Hello world" do not crashes, but my program is heavy, and crashes on the start.  Please help!

Comment: How do you know the crash is in this? What causes it to crash? What is the call stack at the time of the crash?

Comment: Also, if you want to run a program, why aren't you using [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) ? `openUrl` will *open* the file in a way that depends on the desktop's configuration, not nessarily *run* it even if it is executable.

Answer (score 0):

Use QProcess to run a program with Qt, It gives a lot of control about the output and state of the process. QDesktopServices::openUrl is most used to open files and it will depend on your desktop environment if it run certain programs or not.